# How to access properties of another file from main.qml after they are modified by C++ code first

Tags: c++, qml, qt5

I’m having problems with QML and C++. If someone could take a look at this piece of code and tell me what I am doing wrong. I ‘m just trying to print “`msg.author`” on a window (main window) but everytime I try to access it from main.qml there’s an error saying `msg is not defined`. Thank you for your time.

```
main.qml
import QtQuick 2.2
import QtQuick.Window 2.1

Window {

    property alias name: value

    visible: true
    id: main_window
    width: 500; height: width
    color:"black"


}

MyItem.qml
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Window 2.0

Text {
    id: text1
    visible: true 

    width: 100; height: 100
    text: msg.author    // invokes Message::author() to get this value

    color: "green"
    font.pixelSize: 20


    Component.onCompleted: {
        msg.author = "Jonah"  // invokes Message::setAuthor()
    }
```

message.h

```
#ifndef MESSAGE
#define MESSAGE

#include <QObject>
#include <QString>


class Message : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QString author READ author WRITE setAuthor NOTIFY authorChanged)
public:
    void setAuthor(const QString &a) {
        if (a != m_author) {
            m_author = a;
            emit authorChanged();
        }
    }
    QString author() const {
        return m_author;
    }
signals:
    void authorChanged();
private:
    QString m_author;
};

#endif // MESSAGE
```

main.cpp

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>

#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQmlEngine>
#include <QQmlContext>
#include <QQmlComponent>
#include <QDebug>
#include "message.h"


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine_e;
    engine_e.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));

    QQmlEngine engine;
    Message msg;
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("msg", &msg);
    QQmlComponent component(&engine, QUrl::fromLocalFile("main.qml"));


    if(component.status()!=component.Ready){
        if(component.Error){

        qDebug()<<"Error: "<<component.errorString();
    }
}



    return app.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is not working, and the main has two `engine`s. The second is not properly set-up and it should also be noted, from `QQmlApplicationEngine` documentation, that:

> This class **combines a QQmlEngine and QQmlComponent** to provide a convenient way to load a single QML file. It also exposes some central application functionality to QML, which a C++/QML hybrid application would normally control from C++.

Hence, `QQmlApplicationEngine` can perfectly suit your needs and load the QML file. Now, it should also be noted that context properties should ***always*** be set ***before*** loading a QML file. The final correct code is the following:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine_e;

    Message msg;
    engine_e.rootContext()->setContextProperty("msg", &msg);

    engine_e.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
    return app.exec();
}
```

### EDIT

For what concerns QML files, they should be placed inside the resources (as I hope you have done). My test setting is the following:

`main.qml`:

```
import QtQuick 2.3
import QtQuick.Window 2.1

Window {

  //  property alias name: value

    visible: true
    id: main_window
    width: 500; height: width
   // color:"black"

    MyItem {
        anchors.centerIn: parent          // <--- added to the main window to see the result
    } 
}
```

`MyItem.qml`

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Text {
    id: text1
    visible: true


    width: 100; height: 100
    text: msg.author    // invokes Message::author() to get this value

    color: "green"
    font.pixelSize: 20


    Component.onCompleted: {
        msg.author = "Jonah"  // invokes Message::setAuthor()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the corrections. Yet, my main problem still persists. I can't seem to find a way to make these two "things" (QML and C++) to interact with each other. I'm wondering if I really am this stupid or is this task really that hard to learn!??

Comment: What error do you have? I've just copied your code, corrected the main as above, corrected the error in QML code (the missing bracket) and everything works file. What's the matter, exactly?

Comment: The first block( marked as code) contains two .qml files (MyItem.qml and main.qml) now I'm trying to print, in a window, from main.qml-  msg.author (basically the name Johan). When I try to access that it gives me  the eroor "msg is not defined".

Comment: I know...I've just copied `MyItem` inside the main to see the final effect. Ok, I edit with my full example.

Comment: I'm sorry for the trouble you went through. Thnx a lot but does this really work for You?!!!

Comment: Yep, my example works. What error do you get? Did you copied it as it is?

Comment: It works now, thank you. Had to clean and run qmake. I'm gona study your code for a while. Let's see if I can learn something.